# Get last row index on Tabulator js

Tags: html-table, row, tabulator

I want index of the last row, or total row in the table using Tabulator js. Is there any way you can get row count or index of last row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have come up with some digging in the documentation of Tabulator JS.

`var rows = table.getRows().length;`

It will give you the total number of rows.

Comment: can you please add more details. I need to do same thing. How would i render the value to html.